# Office 365 'Delete' Subscriptions for Calendar

Tags: calendar, office365api

I have been using 'Subscriptions' mechanism to get real time updates on Office calendar and mail. Now I just tried to listen for calendar events cancellation using the same mechanism but I noticed that I am not receiving 'delete' notifications for calendar events. Does anybody know if its an issue with api?

Answer (score 0):

Cancelled events are not deleted until and unless user removes the event from the calendar. The event is updated to reflect that it's been canceled.

So you should get an update notification and the event being updated will have `IsCancelled` set to true.

Comment: Okay, but if I simply 'Delete' an event, I should get a notification if I have subscribed to (ChangeType => 'Created,Updated,Deleted'). This does not seem to be working i.e. I do not receive any notification for event deletion.